# how gray release or gated launch while on kubernbetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Does the `k8s` support `gated launch` or called `gray release` ? for example, I deploy a nginx `service` in `k8s` which version is `1.10.2` with `replica = 10`,  then I want to upgrade the `service` to `1.11.5`, I modify the `deployment` and the I use the `kubectl rollout status deployment nginx`, I find all of the 10 pods has been set to `1.11.5`,so how can I reach the status --- 2 pods with verion is `1.11.5` and 8 pods remain old `1.10.2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is referred to as [canary deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#canary-deployments) in the documentation. (See the page linked)

In short:

- add a differentiating label say `track: stable` to your pods in the deployment (do this once and roll it out)
- make a copy of the deployment file, name it `foo-canary` (make sure you do change the name in the file)
- change that label to `track: canary`
- change to `replicas: 2`
- change the image or whatever else you need to and deploy it
- when satisfied with the result change the original deployment and roll it out